# Sequence of blocks

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent which needs to seize two different equipment units, one excavator, and one truck. It seizes excavator first, release it and then it seizes truck. I added some functions to the release excavator block but interestingly the agent goes to seize truck block without going to release excavator block! so thus functions do not work. How this is possible?

Please see the attached file. How can I solve this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird. Have you tried adding any other block in between seize and release exc? In some cases it happens that some code isn't executed (i.e. in the options on a selectOutput) because you defined the conditions in the block inmediately before that. But in your case the counters remain in 0 and the next ones have the same value as the previous ones (you're sure the blocks are properly connected, right? they seem to be connected at first sight).

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for your reply.  Yes they are connected. I talked with AnyLogic support team. There is only a visual bug with these in/out counters that needs to be resolved in the new version of AnyLogic. Yes, I added a delay block in between. :)